# Putting pictures at a particular place (taking the width of the page)

Tags: floats, positioning, overleaf

I'm currently trying to understand what's the best way to set pictures in my Overleaf project at a particular place (taking the width of the page).

I usually do it like this (put a `name.png` file in the `Pictures` folder):

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Pictures/name.png}
    \caption{some text}
    \label{the label}
\end{figure}
```

I adapt the scale until it fits in the width of the page.
Is there a better way to put my pictures ? I want them to appear exacly where I write this code.

Comment: Does image should be from border to border of page or from border to border of text on page? For latter try with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Pictures/name.png}`

Comment: using only [h] is normally not a good idea. If you really want them not to float use the float package and [H]. But this can lead to lots of unwanted white space. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2388

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, you want to force the postion of a `figure` environment in a specific position on the page.

If you really want to do this, you should load the `float` package and pass the `[H]` option to the figure environment (See [Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text/)).

Comment: Positioning is one part of the question. The more important one is to rescale its width automatically, assuming the images do vary in width.